# Perform a scripted find/replace or refactor in IntelliJ IDE

Tags: replace, automation, webstorm, goland

I'm looking to massively rename symbols in a series of projects due to changes in a shared library. That requires to search/replace strings like `pkg1.Map` → `pkg2.Map`.

Since doing this manually is possible but very time consuming, I was looking for a way to create some sort of script or macro to automate the IDE (using GoLand and WebStorm). This doesn't seem easy at all because:

- Macros are too limited and not configurable
- The IDE console has poor documentation, very few examples and seems rather complex
- I could use a command line utility like `sed` and put it into a bash script, but it wouldn't have the IDE's context while doing searches (still I believe it's the easiest way)
- Automating the IDE could open up an interesting world of possibilities

Are there any other suggestions on how to approach it? The best thing in my opinion would be to have a "patch file" that automatically corrects all source code with the new names, using IDE functions.

If you think the IDE console is the way to go, I'm kindly asking for a working example, because I'm not familiar with Groovy and I didn't find anything in the API docs.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, probably Refactor | Rename on the symbol will work? I know that it requires some time depending on the number of your projects but the IDE should rename your symbols accordingly.

Comment: Refactor does work, but I have 50 symbols to refactor for 8 projects. Automating that is the key. For now I used `sed`...